# Adobe Acrobat uncheck checkbox javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to have specific checkboxes checked or unchecked dependent on the checkbox value. When I check the box the other boxes get checked, but if I uncheck the box, the other boxes don't get unchecked. I've tried the Mouse Exit and Mouse Up triggers with the same result.

```
if (this.getField("Check Box2").value == "On")
{
this.getField("Check if this is an").value = "On";
this.getField("Check 1").value = "On";
this.getField("Check Box230").value = "Yes";
}
else //if (this.getField("Check Box2").value == "Off")
{
//this.getField("Check if this is an").value = "Off";
this.getField("Check if this is an").checkThisBox(0, false)
this.getField("Check 1").value = "Off";
this.getField("Check Box230").value = "Off";
}
```

I've tried 2 `if` statements, and an `if/else` as well as the `.value = "Off"` and the `checkThisBox(0, false)` methods. When I run a single line using either method from the console it works.

Comment: it's not in HTML it's in a PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the field names and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and you say it runs from the console so I'll assume it actually is. Your problem then is the event you are attaching your code to. The mouse events fire before the value actually gets updated (see image below for event order). Instead of adding your code to one of the checkboxes, create a new, hidden, field and add your code as a custom calculation for that field. That way your code will run after all of the event processing on the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I thought about that, but then why does it work to check the boxes?

Comment: Using an invisible field didn't work, neither did separating the two functions into two separate Javascripts within Adobe

Comment: Post the PDF somewhere so I can take a look.